# Template For Sharepoint Intranet portal

Tags: site-template, recommendations

I've been asked to create Intranet portal with following features ONLY..

Admin should be able to create/modify/delete Business group/Sub Groups. through an UI
Admin should be able to create/modify/delete Business group user through an UI.
All users should be able to upload document with in their group /sub group.While uploading any document they need to specify filtering parameters and other group level parameters mandatory .
All users should be able to modify uploaded document attributes through an UI after searching it.

user will have access to their group only.

there should only be hyperlinks on Home page for above activities like
User management ,
Group Management,
filter Parameter management,
contribute material ,
material management ,
that's it home page should contain these links ,company logo ,user logged in ..nothing else than that .
by clicking on links -user will navigate to respective page like usermanagement page ..that page will contain forms for user management ..

All the default Sharepoint features like Documnet list ,Appointment ,list ,tasks etc that we see on the right hand side of sharepoint site -shouls not be there ..no ribbons etc ..

plain simple web site ...

Pls. suggest me which template i should use and why ? we only need to use the power of Content management system -as the company needs to store loads of document and a fast searching --that is the reason to choose MOSS -else this could have been achieved by normal ASP.NET web site..

Thanks ..

Comment: This isn't relevant to software development - could go to SharePoint.SE

Answer (score 1):

I believe the optimal ways you can do it are:

1. attend several trainig courses and read multiple good books on SP practicing all that time
2. hire SharePoint consultant to do it for you

I'm pretty sure that community just cannot do all the work for you by answering a questions

Answer (score 0):

First at all it is not the best way to strip out the Ribbon and the Quicklaunch-Area, because you cut off some useful SharePoint functionality.

But there is some help you could find in this [article via msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430141.aspx).

An other way is to start from scratch with the help of the famous [Starter Master Pages for SP 2010](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/).

There is also another helpful project at codeplex "Show or Hide SharePoint 2010 ribbon based on SharePoint Groups" to show/hide the Ribbon for specific groups, without coding.